# Reddish Images of screenshots of android screen

Tags: java, android-emulator, android

Has anyone tried out Android Screenshot Library (ASL)? It has a native program which is run by adb and has a service which connects to it via a socket and retrieve info like width, height, bpp, and the actual data of the screenshot.

On the emulator the images are coming blank (fully black).

And when tried on my samsung galaxy ace (non-rooted), it gives a proper screenshot but the image is a reddish image.

If anybody knows why it comes reddish, maybe someone having knowledge of graphics could even tell me why the image is so.

Has anyone tried out ASL? Do you get proper screenshots of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't, but in most phones, you can save a screenshot by holding the Home key and then tapping the unlock key. I haven't had any problem with those. I am not sure it works on an emulator.

Comment: even i do know frm gingerbread onwards..
screenshot comes in-built in the OS itself by pressing the home and power key..i do get screenshots on my ace as well..
but my motto is not to have a screenshot app..just that i want that facility to be there in my other application..
its a part of that app..need it..

so if anybody there could help me out..